# $scope not getting any values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

So this is how my index.html is structured.

```
<html ng-app='information'>
<body ng-controller="FirstController as first>
<div ng-controller="SecondController as second>

  <div id="information">
    <myOwnDirective ng-controller="ThirdController as thirdCtrl"></myOwnDirective>
  </div>
```

This is my custom directive.

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('information', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.directive('myOwnDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'my-own-directive.html',

        };  
    });
```

This is a custom directive template. my-own-directive.html

```
<uib-accordion tag ng-repeat="info in first">
<form ng-submit="thirdCtrl.updateInformation()">
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="someprop">Property</label> <input type="text" name="someprop"
            class="form-control" ng-model="info.propValue"
            ng-readonly="info.propValue">
    </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Click</button>
</form>
```

This is my script file: myScript.js

```
(function() {

    angular.module('information').controller('ThirdController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {

        console.log("In third controller");          // This prints     
        this.updateInformation = function() { 
            console.log("Inside updateInformation");
            console.log("Inside scope is: "+ $scope)     // It is undefined
        };   
    }]);       
})();
```

What I want to get is get value of info.propValue from the scope but I cant seem to get it. It always shows up as undefined. I have a very long form whose contents I want to read but I cant seem to get the values. Once I have them I will bemaking an Ajax call using $http. Also, if I try to invoke function updateInformation() by doing $scope.updateInformation(), it doesnt invoke, but it does get called if I do this.updateInformation(). Why ?? What am I missing or what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Have been stuck on it for quite a while. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the right scope. Directive scope and Controller scope are different.

Comment: How do I access them separately? Sorry I dont know much about this. Thanks.

Comment: What is the version of angular that you're using? Trying to reproduce this [using v1.4.9](http://plnkr.co/edit/h7MGu7CcjkUIidA4xLzu?p=preview) I can see that the scope is working different than your results.

Comment: I am sourcing it from here: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js. Also when you said "scope is working different than your results", what did it mean? What are you seeing please?

Comment: @ Lucio.. if I change the version and try to do console.log($scope), I get this in console b {$$childTail: b, $$childHead: b, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array[1], $$listeners: Object…}   . I tried to go over through "b" and find my data but I dont think that is there, but atleast something is showing up now. Am I doing this correctly please? Thanks.

Comment: @ Lucio.. any suggestions on the issue ? I still havent been able to make progress on it. Thanks.